# Sharing script between different switch case condition

Tags: javascript

Condition 1 should perform task 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 9.
Condition 2 should perform task 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, and 9.
Condition 3 should perform task 8 and 9.

The following is easy to read, but will not work as the second `condition1` and `condition2` tasks will not be executed as the earlier `break` causes the script to exit the switch statement.

```
var condition='condition1'; 
switch(condition) {
    case 'condition1':
    case 'condition2':
        console.log('do task 1');
        console.log('do task 2');
        console.log('do task 3');
        break;
    case 'condition1':
        console.log('do task 4');
        console.log('do task 5');
        break;
    case 'condition2':
        console.log('do task 6');
        console.log('do task 7');
        break;
    case 'condition3':
        console.log('do task 8');
        break;
}
console.log('do task 9');
```

The following should work, but it is not as easy to read, and will become increasingly more difficult as more functionality is shared between the different conditions.

```
var condition='condition1'; 
switch(condition) {
    case 'condition1':
    case 'condition2':
        console.log('do task 1');
        console.log('do task 2');
        console.log('do task 3');
        switch(condition) {
            case 'condition1':
                console.log('do task 4');
                console.log('do task 5');
                break;
            case 'condition2':
                console.log('do task 6');
                console.log('do task 7');
                break;
        }
        break;
    case 'condition3':
        console.log('do task 8');
        break;
}
console.log('do task 9');
```

Again, this should work, but coming up with descriptive names for the different groups will be problematic.

```
var condition='condition1'; 
switch(condition) {
    case 'condition1':
        task_group_1_2_3();
        task_group_4_5();
        break;
    case 'condition2':
        task_group_1_2_3();
        task_group_6_7();
        break;
    case 'condition3':
        console.log('do task 8');
        break;
}
console.log('do task 9');

function task_group_1_2_3() {
    console.log('do task 1');
    console.log('do task 2');
    console.log('do task 3');    
}

function task_group_4_5() {
    console.log('do task 4');
    console.log('do task 5');
}

function task_group_6_7() {
    console.log('do task 6');
    console.log('do task 7');
}
```

What is the cleanest way to create a switch statement which shares some script between different case conditions?

Comment: _“Condition 1 should perform task 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 9. Condition 2 should perform task 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, and 9. Condition 3 should perform task 8 and 9.”_ – that is information I’d rather put into arrays ... pick the right sub-array based on the condition key, and then loop over the elements and execute the tasks ... I don’t think building complex, even nested switch statements is going to make this more readable/maintainable.

Comment: @CBroe  Ah, another way to skin a cat, and a better way at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the conditions into an object and the tasks as well and iterate the array with the task.

You could use a right name instead of a number as key name.

```js
var tasks = {
        1: function () { console.log(1); },
        2: function () { console.log(2); },
        3: function () { console.log(3); },
        4: function () { console.log(4); },
        5: function () { console.log(5); },
        6: function () { console.log(6); },
        7: function () { console.log(7); },
        8: function () { console.log(8); },
        9: function () { console.log(9); }
    },
    conditions = {
        1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9],
        2: [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9],
        3: [8, 9]
    },
    condition = 1;

conditions[condition].forEach(function (a) { tasks[a](); });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice approach.  I know I originally used non-descriptive "condition 1" names, but obviously can and should use more descriptive names that 1, 2, and 3.

Answer (score 1):

Since multiple conditions can call a single task, it may be a better idea to implement condition-to-tasks mapping and scan through it.
This way, you can easily add / remove conditions and add / remove tasks.

```js
function task1() { console.log("Task 1."); }
function task2() { console.log("Task 2."); }
function task3() { console.log("Task 3."); }
function task4() { console.log("Task 4."); }
function task5() { console.log("Task 5."); }
function task6() { console.log("Task 6."); }
function task7() { console.log("Task 7."); }
function task8() { console.log("Task 8."); }
function task9() { console.log("Task 9."); }

var conditionTaskMapping = {
  "condition1": [task1, task2, task3, task4, task5, task9],
  "condition2": [task1, task2, task3, task6, task7],
  "condition3": [task8, task9]
};

document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
  var condition = document.querySelector("input").value;
  if (!conditionTaskMapping[condition])
  {
    console.log("Unknown condition: " + condition);
    return;
  } 
  
  for (var task of conditionTaskMapping[condition])
  {
    task();
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="text" value="condition1"/>
<button>Go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe nested switch are not recommanded (switch 2). 
So, I find your first switch more readable than others.
Perhaps you can split it in two switch.

```
var condition='condition1'; 
switch(condition) {
    case 'condition1':
    case 'condition2':
        console.log('do task 1');
        console.log('do task 2');
        console.log('do task 3');
        break;
}

switch(condition) {
    case 'condition1':
        console.log('do task 4');
        console.log('do task 5');
        break;
    case 'condition2':
        console.log('do task 6');
        console.log('do task 7');
        break;
    case 'condition3':
        console.log('do task 8');
        break;
}
console.log('do task 9');
```

Comment: I didn't know they were depreciated.  Sure?  Maybe also in also languages such as PHP?

Comment: not deprecated but not recommanded. You have to follow a code line (I follow the eslint code line, and nested switch are not recommanded in it).

Answer (score 0):

You could move you condition inside an object

```js
const conditions = {
  "condition1" : {
    "foo": ()=>console.log('do task 1'),
    "foo2": ()=>console.log('do task 2'),
    "foo3": ()=>console.log('do task 3'),
    "foo4": ()=>console.log('do task 4'),
    "foo5": ()=>console.log('do task 5'),
    "foo6": ()=>console.log('do task 9')
  },
  "condition2": {
    "foo": ()=>console.log('do task 1'),
    "foo2": ()=>console.log('do task 2'),
    "foo3": ()=>console.log('do task 3'),
    "foo4": ()=>console.log('do task 6'),
    "foo5": ()=>console.log('do task 7'),
    "foo6": ()=>console.log('do task 9')
  },
  "condition3": {
    "foo": ()=>console.log('do task 8'),
    "foo2": ()=>console.log('do task 9')
  }
};

Object.values(conditions['condition1']).forEach(f=>f());
```

Comment: This too requires duplicating the script (`console.log('do task 1')` but it could be more in each.

Comment: @user1032531 This can simply be a reference to your actual function. You don't have to copy paste all the functions

Answer (score 0):

For fun since it is a cosmetic dilemma :)

```
function f(sCond, iTask) {
    // matrix of dependencies
    var m = {
               'condition1' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9], 
               'condition2' : [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9], 
               'condition3' : [8, 9]
            };

    return m[sCond].indexOf(iTask) !== -1;
};

f(condition, 1) && console.log('do task1');
f(condition, 2) && console.log('do task2');
f(condition, 3) && console.log('do task3');
f(condition, 4) && console.log('do task4');
f(condition, 5) && console.log('do task5');
f(condition, 6) && console.log('do task6');
f(condition, 7) && console.log('do task7');
f(condition, 8) && console.log('do task8');
f(condition, 9) && console.log('do task9');
```